# eclipse - auto-indent works not like formatter

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, indentation

I've setup code formatter in Eclipse Juno to behave in a certain way, but it seems like it doesn't apply to auto-indenting (when you press `Enter` and Eclipse indents the new line automatically). For example, the following fragment is how my `Ctrl+Shift+F` formats it:

```
dao.list()
    .equal("a", 2)
    .greater("b", 7)
    .get();
```

But when I'm entering the code by hand, that's what I get:

```
dao.list()
.equal("a", 2)
.greater("b", 7)
.get();
```

And that's just one example, everything else also behaves this way. It seems like auto-indentation adheres to the default formatting style ignoring the selected one.

So I would be glad if anyone told me how to set up auto-indentation behave just like the configured code formatter.